# how to change the default CC command on mac os?

Tags: macintosh, compiler

```
export PATH=./ndk_tools/bin/:${PATH}
export CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
export CXX=arm-linux-androideabi-g++
echo \
"$CC"
CC --version
```

I use the script to change the default CC command, but it doesn't work for me on Mac.

print:

```
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

where is my fault?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example

```
export PATH=./ndk_tools/bin/:${PATH}
export CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
export CXX=arm-linux-androideabi-g++
echo \
"$CC"
CC --version
```

the last line uses the literal *name* **`CC`** (which is conventionally a C++ compiler) rather than a shell *variable* **`$CC`** (which would use the environment variable that you exported).

Perhaps you meant

```
export PATH=./ndk_tools/bin/:${PATH}
export CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
export CXX=arm-linux-androideabi-g++
echo \
"$CC"
$CC --version
```

You might also want to simply make `cc` the one from `ndk_tools` by making a symbolic link to that (named "cc") on your `PATH`, but that would interfere with native use of the compiler.  So environment variables (and selective use) is the way to go.

In a makefile, you would use this symbol with parentheses or braces, e.g.,`$(CC)` or `${CC}`.  Without the braces, `make` would see **`$C`**`C`, which is not what you want.  You can set the variable in the makefile in various ways, e.g.,

```
make CC="$CC"
make -e
```

Most of the time I would be using the value directly *in* the makefile, due to using either autoconf- or imake-based builds.  For those cases, exporting the variable would be less important.

Comment: That might be not enough if you want to change default cc globally and not just in your instance of one shell. Keep in mind that programs like cmake or the lsp named clangd and the package manager conan all tend to invoke your compiler indirectly.

Comment: That wasn't what OP was asking.  Different questions get different answers.